# C code for listing files of a directory is not working

Tags: c, windows, winapi, directory-listing

I am using Windows 10 platform and compiled the following C code using the VS buildtools. The code attempts to list file/folders at a given location. Compilation went fine, but I am not getting the desired results. The program writes the message 'Listing files ...', waits for some time and exits. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

HANDLE fhandle;
WIN32_FIND_DATAA* file_details;
int next_file = 1;

char* path = strcat(argv[1], "/*"); 
printf("Listing files for %s\n", path);
fhandle = FindFirstFileA(path, file_details);

if(fhandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    
    while(next_file){
        printf("%s\n", file_details->cFileName);
        next_file = FindNextFileA(fhandle, file_details);   
    }
        
}
else{
    printf("Error!");
}

FindClose(fhandle);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you're getting no output, but the logic of your loop is broken. The last file name will  never be printed.

Comment: On what basis?  The loop looks okay to me.  `FindNextFileA` returns `FALSE` when there are no more results.  The main issues I see are unsafe concatenation of data on a string, and passing an uninitialized pointer to `FindFirstFileA`.  Both of these are undefined behavior, and show a general lack in understanding of how to use pointers.

Comment: Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) shows how to correctly use `FindFirstFile`.

Comment: Did you run this with your fgavorite debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.

First of all, you cannot pass `char* path = strcat(argv[1], "/*");` assign a concatenated string to `path`, because `argv[1]` is a `const char *`.

Second, when you use `WIN32_FIND_DATAA*`, there is no memory space for it, so it cannot get the returned data.

Here is the modified example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    HANDLE fhandle;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA* file_details = (WIN32_FIND_DATAA*)malloc(sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATAA));
    memset(file_details, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATAA));
    int next_file = 1;
    char path[100];
    strcpy(path, argv[1]);
    strcat(path, "/*");
    printf("Listing files for %s\n", path);
    fhandle = FindFirstFileA(path, file_details);

    if (fhandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

        while (next_file) {
            printf("%s\n", file_details->cFileName);
            next_file = FindNextFileA(fhandle, file_details);
        }

    }
    else {
        printf("Error!");
    }
    free(file_details);
    FindClose(fhandle);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Allocating memory space for WIN32_FIND_DATAA type solved my problem. But, the sample code given with [Microsoft documentation for FindFirstFileA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) does not allocate any memory space for this. Is that an instance of bad sample code? I wonder.

Comment: @PradeepPillai The document uses an object of type WIN32_FIND_DATAA instead of a pointer, so there is no need to allocate memory.

Comment: Now I understand. Pointers are really evil !! :-)

Comment: @PradeepPillai Never use a pointer to a dynamically allocated object if you can use an automatic variable.  Creating dynamically allocated objects is SLOW and remembering to allocate and deallocate is hard.  Automatic variables are always better unless you need a pointer.